# Nitrous.IO and Meteor images

Tags: image, audio, meteor, nitrousio

I use **Nitrous.IO** as environment to code with **Meteor**.
But, when I want to replace an image, even *if I erase the old one and then upload the new one* (with the same name) the old picture is still shown. Even after a restart of Meteor or Nitrous.IO.
What should I do?
Same goes to MP3 files.

Comment: Maybe this is a caching error of your browser? Try strg+F5, because this force (chrome) to ignore cached content.

Comment: I've sure tried that my good friend. Thanks for the attention mate.